# importing data into Excel from a JSON file by a web url

Tags: json, excel, powerquery

I am importing data into Excel from a JSON file by a web url, using `From Web` under the `Data` tab power query.

Most of the data is coming in correctly but some of the data is coming is as `[List]` as the cell value

All [List] data is of the form `aaa|bbb|ccc` i.e piped delimited

[image]

Should look like this

[image]

Is it possible to get the data to show properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, transform the column. If the value is a list, then combine the values with a "|" as separator, e.g.:

```
let
    Source = #table({"Sector"},{{"Non-profit"},{{"Business & industry","Govenrnment"}}}),
    TextCombined = Table.TransformColumns(Source, {{"Sector", each if _ is list then Text.Combine(_,"|") else _, type text}})
in
    TextCombined
```

Comment: Mark, thank you!.  I am a complete beginner in this, can you tell me where to add this.  I tried adding it in the `advanced editor` but I get error as there is already a `let` and `in` statement

Comment: From my 5 lines of code, copy the last 3 lines, remove your last 2 lines of code (the line with "in" and the line after it), add a comma after your last line of code, paste my 3 lines after that line, and replace "Source" with the name of the step of the line to which you just added a comma.

Comment: Unfortunately you also didn't understand the help offered by Colin on TechNet. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=powerquery,sqlkjpowerpivotforexcel&filter=alltypes&sort=lastpostdesc